# Problem starting emulator in Android Studio (flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, avd-manager

everyone.
I do my first steps in android development and stumble upon the problem with running the emulator from inside the Android Studio.
Created "Galaxy Nexus" via AVD Manager with Android 9.0 onboard:
[AVD manager settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjCHM.png)

When trying to start it up - I've received the error "The emulator process for AVD Galaxy_Nexus_API_28 has terminated.":
[AVD error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1N9k.png)

I have tried to:

1. delete the virtual device and to create it again - to the same result;
2. delete "Android Emulator" via SDK Manager - to the same result.

Also I've checked if VM-related options are enabled in BIOS of the motherboard of my PC (an act of despair, but...).

So, maybe someone can help me? Where to look next?

Comment: Have you tried installing the other OS such as armeabi-v7a or arm64, maybe your problem is with your arch?

Comment: I found the solution. It is all because of non-English characters existed in my user profile name - pretty dumb... :-(

[link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50738#issuecomment-719511733)

Comment: so glad that you had found a solution but it is a common bug